# Digital signatures with CRYSTALS-DILITHIUM with ASP.NET and Bouncy Castle

Tags: c#, asp.net, cryptography, digital-signature, bouncycastle

I am writing a peer-to-peer file sharing system in `ASP.NET`. The client needs to be able to validate that their files are coming from a trustworthy author. The client has the public keys of authors whom they trust, and the authors should digitally sign files which they share.

I would like to use [CRYSTALS-DILITHIUM](https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/post-quantum-cryptography/post-quantum-cryptography-standardization/round-3-submissions) for generating and verifying these signatures and am using [Bouncy Castle's .NET library v2.2.0](https://bouncycastle.org/csharp/index.html) for my implementation of the algorithm.

How can I:

1. Generate a new keypair
2. Use the private key to sign a message
3. Use the public key to verify the message

Here is my example code thus far:

Note that some items, such as the parameters for `new DilithiumPrivateKeyParameters(...)` are missing because I do not know what should go there.

```cs
public static void Generate ()
{
    DilithiumKeyPairGenerator generator = new DilithiumKeyPairGenerator();
    generator.Init(new DilithiumKeyGenerationParameters(
        new SecureRandom(),
        DilithiumParameters.Dilithium5Aes
        ));

    AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = generator.GenerateKeyPair();

    // All the later methods need bytes of these key - how do I get them?
    AsymmetricKeyParameter publicKey = keyPair.Public;
    AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKey = keyPair.Private;
}

public static void Sign ()
{
    DilithiumSigner signer = new DilithiumSigner();

    // What do I put in all these parameters?
    signer.Init(true, new DilithiumPrivateKeyParameters(
        DilithiumParameters.Dilithium5Aes,
                // byte[] rho,
                // byte[] K,
                // byte[] tr,
                // byte[] s1,
                // byte[] s2,
                // byte[] t1,
                // byte[] t2,
        ));

    string messageText = "Important Message!";

    // Send the message and signature
    byte[] message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageText);
    byte[] signature = signer.GenerateSignature(message);
}

public void Verify (byte[] publicKey, byte[] message, byte[] signature)
{
    DilithiumSigner verifier = new DilithiumSigner();

    // The constructor asks for "pkEncoded" - how should the bytes be encoded?
    verifier.Init(false, new DilithiumPublicKeyParameters(publicKey));

    bool good = verifier.VerifySignature(message, signature);
}
```

Comment: The source code of C#/BouncyCastle also contains tests, e.g. [here](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/master/crypto/test/src/pqc/crypto/test/CrystalsDilithiumTest.cs). Maybe this helps.

Comment: @Topaco Yep took a look at some more examples including the BC tests and https://stackoverflow.com/q/29423997/13111872 - now have an answer so thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working sample of the signing and verification - nothing that a little bit of type-casting can't fix!

Links I found helpful:

1. [Bouncy Castle Sign and Verify SHA256 Certificate With C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29423997/13111872)
2. [How to generate Private key from string using BouncyCastle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54366089/13111872)
3. [Bouncy Castle C# - getting public key object from byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63793612/13111872)
4. https://github.com/CryptoKass/dilithium/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dilithium/Start.java
5. https://github.com/rodbate/bouncycastle-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/chapter2/KeyGeneratorExample.java
6. https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/master/crypto/src/pqc/crypto/crystals/kyber/KyberEngine.cs

I needed to maintain the keys as `Dilithium...KeyParameters`, not `byte[]`s or `ICypherKeyParameters`. This gives me access to the correct `Rho, K, etc.` properties and the `GetEncoded()` method.

```
public static void Test ()
{
    AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair1 = Generate();
    AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair2 = Generate();

    byte[] message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Important Message!");
    byte[] signature = Sign((DilithiumPrivateKeyParameters) keyPair1.Private, message);

    // Returns TRUE
    bool check1 = Verify((DilithiumPublicKeyParameters) keyPair1.Public, message, signature);
    // Returns FALSE (as expected)
    bool check2 = Verify((DilithiumPublicKeyParameters) keyPair2.Public, message, signature);
}

public static AsymmetricCipherKeyPair Generate ()
{
    DilithiumKeyPairGenerator generator = new DilithiumKeyPairGenerator();
    generator.Init(new DilithiumKeyGenerationParameters(
        new SecureRandom(),
        DilithiumParameters.Dilithium5Aes
        ));

    AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = generator.GenerateKeyPair();

    return keyPair;
}

public static byte[] Sign (DilithiumPrivateKeyParameters privateKey, byte[] message)
{
    DilithiumSigner signer = new DilithiumSigner();

    // What do I put in all these parameters?
    signer.Init(true, new DilithiumPrivateKeyParameters(
        DilithiumParameters.Dilithium5Aes,
                privateKey.Rho,
                privateKey.K,
                privateKey.Tr,
                privateKey.S1,
                privateKey.S2,
                privateKey.T0,
                privateKey.T1
        ));

    byte[] signature = signer.GenerateSignature(message);
    return signature;
}

public static bool Verify (DilithiumPublicKeyParameters publicKey, byte[] message, byte[] signature)
{
    DilithiumSigner verifier = new DilithiumSigner();

    // The constructor asks for "pkEncoded" - how should the bytes be encoded?
    verifier.Init(false, new DilithiumPublicKeyParameters(
        DilithiumParameters.Dilithium5Aes,
        publicKey.GetEncoded()
        ));

    return verifier.VerifySignature(message, signature);
}
```

Comment: It's not necessary to make copies of the private and public key; the Private, Public parts of the generated key pair can be used directly in the Init method.